# Using $http outside of controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to split up and organise an AngularJS application so that it isn't just a 5000 line main.js file. Splitting off directives, etc. and using `make` to build working code is all fine. However, my controller has a couple of moderately complex internal classes. These used to be defined roughly as follows (only one shown for clarity):

```
var app = angular.module("infrasense", []);
app.controller("AppMain", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    function NavTree(dbMain, dbTimeout, allTagTypes, allAttTypes) {
        ...
    }
    NavTree.prototype = {
        ...
    }

    ...
    $scope.navTree[0] = new NavTree(dbMain, dbTimeout);
    ...

});
```

The NavTree class (which holds a hierarchical tree of sites and assets in a data logging application) is rendered using a directive and uses $http internally to talk to a backend server (the tree is too complex to be held in memory at once, plus it changes).

In order to keep using a simple (cat-based) tool to generate my final code I want to move NavTree out of the controller. I currently do this by passing $http into it from inside the controller:

```
function NavTree($http, dbMain, dbTimeout, allTagTypes, allAttTypes) {
    ...
    this.$http = $http;
    ...
}

app.controller("AppMain", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    ...
    $scope.navTree[0] = new NavTree($http, dbMain, dbTimeout);
    ...
});
```

This works but feels inelegant and non-AngularJS-ish. Can anyone suggest the "proper" way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Consider making NavTree a service.

Comment: As @kju said, create a service and inject the service into the controllers that needed. Inside your service, make the `$http` call and pass along the promise to the controller.

Comment: Thanks! I'm off to investigate services and see if I can convert my code into one. I'll edit my question to include a solution when/if I have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! I am now a good proportion of the way towards moving these inelegant internal classes out of main.js and into services, where they belong.

The key realisation, which I'd missed when reading the documentation but which was restated in "[I Wish I Knew Then What I Know Now — Life With AngularJS](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/08/09/i-wish-i-knew-then-what-i-know-now-life-with-angularjs/)" is that services are just singletons which work with dependency injection.

My service is defined as follows (where "Popup" is another service that manages popup windows for error messages):

```
app.factory("ThingTree", function (Popup, $q, $http) {

    // Database information. This is set up by the "init" function.
    // (There's only one DB, and this way I only have to pass its
    // connection info once.)
    var dbMain = "";
    var dbTimeout = 0;
    ...

    // Each level of the tree is an array of these tree objects.
    function TreeNode() {}
    TreeNode.prototype = {
        open: function() { ... }
        ...
    };

    return {

        // Initialise the database connection.
        init: function(myDbMain, myDbTimeout) {

            dbMain = myDbMain;
            dbTimeout = myDbTimeout;
            ...

        },

        // Create a tree and return the root node.
        create: function() { ... },

        ...

    }

});
```

Thanks for the prods in the right direction!